# How to transform elements to widgets?

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-widgets

I'm working on a GWT website generated with elements:

```
DivElement footerElement = Document.get().createDivElement();
footerElement.setAttribute("id", "mainFooter");

HeadingElement headingElement = Document.get().createHElement(2);
headingElement.setInnerText("This is a footer block");

RootPanel.get().add(footerElement );
```

I want to test some layout panels disposals, but I read that I can only add widgets to layout panels.

Are they some way to transform my elements into widgets without write again all my IHM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with something like

```
FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();
HTML wrap = new HTML().wrap(myElement);
panel.add(wrap);
RootPanel.get().add(panel);
```

note : the `FlowPanel` is not strictly necessary. It adds a `<div>` around your elements (and `HTML.wrap()` will add one too). A panel could be helpful if you want to group elements/widgets together.

Comment: To wrap an element it should be already attach to the document. In the end I use something like `HTML wrap = new HTML(myElement.getinnerHtml());`